# TabBar's background color gets change on tab selection

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbaritem

I don't know why this is happening, I checked it on my storyboard, for my code, I've searched similar questions but didn't find anything.

In my tabBar I have 4 tabs, when I selecting tab #2 tabBars background color gets darken but when I select any other tab it works fine. See the image for better understanding.

tab1 selected 
[image]

tab2 selected (and the background color also get changed

[image]
tab3 selected , and now background color gets normal

[image]

Comment: what render mode property you set for the tab image ?

Comment: render mode ? sorry bro i didn't get you @Shubhank , can you elaborate ?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarItem_Class/index.html read customizing appearance here

Comment: How are you changing the colors?

Comment: UITabBar.appearance().translucent = false in Appdelegate

Answer (score 0):

I think that you are setting tab bar color when presenting 2nd Tab. So remove the background color in the second tab. If you can't still find that try to reset the color when view the tab :-

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    self.tabBarController?.tabBar.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```